# Can I use both LESS and SCSS in the same project or do I have to convert?

Tags: sass, less, gruntjs

I wonder if it is possible to use both LESS and SCSS in the same project, meaning using Grunt to compress and minify both types of files in to one css file? The reason I am asking is that I was planning on using MMenu (which is written in SCSS) with a project that I have already started which is written in LESS. Or do I have to convert the MMenu SCSS files to less? I found the following Grunt task https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-refactor but am uncertain if it is worth the effort since there are a few compatibility issues.

Does anyone have experience using both LESS and SCSS in the same gruntfile?

Here is my gruntfile if anyone would feel like helping out.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
  },
  all: [
    'Gruntfile.js',
    'assets/js/*.js',
    '!assets/js/scripts.min.js'
  ]
},
less: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'assets/css/main.min.css': [
        'assets/less/app.less'
      ]
    },
    options: {
      compress: true,
      // LESS source map
      // To enable, set sourceMap to true and update sourceMapRootpath based on your install
      sourceMap: true,
      sourceMapFilename: 'assets/css/main.min.css.map',
      sourceMapRootpath: '/app/themes/thenewstheme/'
    }
  }
},
uglify: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'assets/js/scripts.min.js': [
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/transition.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/alert.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/button.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/carousel.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/collapse.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/dropdown.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/modal.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/tooltip.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/popover.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/scrollspy.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/tab.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/bootstrap/affix.js',
        'assets/js/plugins/*.js',
        'assets/js/_*.js'
      ]
    },
    options: {
      // JS source map: to enable, uncomment the lines below and update sourceMappingURL based on your install
       sourceMap: 'assets/js/scripts.min.js.map',
       sourceMappingURL: '/app/themes/thenewstheme/assets/js/scripts.min.js.map'
    }
  }
},
version: {
  options: {
    file: 'lib/scripts.php',
    css: 'assets/css/main.min.css',
    cssHandle: 'roots_main',
    js: 'assets/js/scripts.min.js',
    jsHandle: 'roots_scripts'
  }
},
watch: {
  less: {
    files: [
      'assets/less/*.less',
      'assets/less/bootstrap/*.less'
    ],
    tasks: ['less', 'version']
  },
  js: {
    files: [
      '<%= jshint.all %>'
    ],
    tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify', 'version']
  },
  livereload: {
    // Browser live reloading
    // https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#live-reloading
    options: {
      livereload: true
    },
    files: [
      'assets/css/main.min.css',
      'assets/js/scripts.min.js',
      'templates/*.php',
      '*.php'
    ]
  }
},
clean: {
  dist: [
    'assets/css/main.min.css',
    'assets/js/scripts.min.js'
  ]
}
});

// Load tasks
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-wp-version');

// Register tasks
grunt.registerTask('default', [
'clean',
'less',
'uglify',
'version'
]);
grunt.registerTask('dev', [
'watch'
]);

};
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is *yes, you can*.

But because `SASS` and `LESS` have a slightly different syntax - a difference that is only growing as I type, you would end up having to maintain each separately.

If that is not a problem and you would rather try it, I'd recommend using `Compass` ([grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass)) to deal with `SASS`.

I would also make sure that each one does its thing as separately from the other as possible. If you'd still want to share the `css` folder for outputting both, work out a naming pattern that would prevent `LESS`'s output from overwriting the `SASS`'s one.

Building on that, you could concatenate the resulting `CSS` files (compiled separately by each task) into one, with the help of yet another task, like [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin).

Comment: Just a little comment on my own preference: I tried both, went `SASS` and never looked back. ;)